# iOS 8 - automatically resize UIImageView using size classes and aspect ratio

Tags: class, ios8, size, aspect-ratio

I have an ImageView and I want it to set its width to the quarter of its container view's width using aspect ratio.

```
width imageView = width container / 4;
```

Thanks